# Is there a way to "transpose" from scalar product EA.EB to AE.BE?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am wondering if there is an easy way to "transpose" from the result of the scalar product EA.EB to AE.BE ?
In my case, EA.EB = 1/2

Comment: Apparently, In my case EA.EB = AE.BE ! Is this a generality ?

Comment: With $EA$ you mean the vector with first end in $E$ and second end in $A$? In this case $EA\cdot EB=AE\cdot BE$ for all $A,B,E$, because modules are the same and angle beetween $EA$ and $EB$ is the same as the one beetween $AE$ and $BE$ (same sign also).

Comment: @MattAllegro I don't understand exactly what do you mean ! That's probably because I am not a native english speaker nor very good at math...

Comment: Hi! Please accept any of the two answers below, if this thread is solved. Otherwise, let us discuss anything unclear :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If $EA=\mathbf{v}$ and $EB=\mathbf{w}$, then $AE=-\mathbf{v}$ and $BE=-\mathbf{w}$, so
$$
AE \cdot BE = (-\mathbf{v}) \cdot (-\mathbf{w}) = (-1)^2 \, (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w} = EA \cdot EB
.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you denote with $EA$ the vector with first end in $E$ and second end in $A$, then
$$EA\cdot EB=AE\cdot BE\quad\forall A,B,E.$$
In fact, module of $EA$ is the same as $AE$, module of $EB$ is the same as $BE$ and the angle beetween $EA$ and $EB$ is the same as the one beetween $AE$ and $BE$ (the "sign" of the angle is also the same).